Why do non-prime order curves faciliate efficient computation?
Most common elliptic curves in use today (Edwards, Montgomery and the likes) have small cofactors. The reason we seem to want these curves in practice is because they facilitate fast scalar multiplication. On the other hand, much of public key cryptography relies on groups of prime order.
Of course, there are ways to clear cofactors and solutions like Decaf and Ristretto offer ways to perform prime-order group operations efficiently. However, at the heart of these techniques, we still rely on curves of non-prime order.
What are the precise mathematical properties that makes these curves easier to do computation over?

Is there any "exception-free" coordinates system for Weierstrass curves?

This does not address the question.

Did you read it completely? It gives more details than the current answer, they both have unified addition laws, however, non Montgomery Curves are a bit slower, that it.

It doesn't explain precisely why, which is my question. I can look more into it, thanks.

why? Because no one yet find a better way.

Composite Order Curves like Edwards, Montgomery were preferred because they have complete/unified addition laws - i.e. Same formula can be used for both addition & doubling. Also special cases for Point at Infinity aren't required.
This leads to a cleaner implementation which is also less prone to bugs.
However, now there are also complete addition laws for Prime Order Curves - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/complete-2.pdf

Thanks! This is true, but these formulas are still faster and much simpler for
other elliptic curves such as (twisted) Edwards, Hessian,
Jacobi quartics or Jacobi intersections. Source: the Decaf paper
